# Acumatica Portal integration with Wordpress and SSO

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, acumatica

I'm working on setting up a Acumatica Portal.  The actual Acumatica Portal (portal.acumatica.com) is using a WordPress wrapper and SSO. This is pretty much exactly what my customer is after.

I'm not familiar with using SSO, so I'm wondering if anyone has experience with something like this. I'd love just a push in the correct direction on which pieces I need to make something like that work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I originally wrote the SAML-based SSO wrapper for portal.Acumatica.com many years ago. You’re in luck, I had recorded a video on YouTube that explains the different steps. Link: https://youtu.be/_b_qVnFGFTE. It’s been a while and things have probably changed in Wordpress since then. The original project can still be found here on GitHub: https://github.com/Acumatica/acumatica-saml-idp/

Comment: So this has been a fairly amazing adventure. Your code still basically works and I can't even begin to imagine how I would have gotten anywhere without it.  I've got it working on my test environment, but when I try to create a cert and publish it to the Acumatica Hosted environment I get an error like this "The specified network password is not correct. at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" which would imply that the password is incorrect. That said, I'm 99% sure it's an issue with the code not having access to the certificate store. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Can you share the full message and stack trace of the error message?

Comment: That error you see is the error opening the cert. Support told me I can't have a Self Signed Cert on the SaaS hosted environment. Does that make sense to you? How did you come up with saml.pfx that you used in the video?

Comment: It’s been too long! But I don’t remember having to get a paid certificate for it to work. Maybe they have added additional restrictions since then. To get a better trace, can you try turning on the request profiler with full error logging?